# Raise modal view controller with UItabbar still exist

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm using this:

https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/RaisedCenterTabBar

and I raised the modal view by using:

In BaseViewController.m the center button is added in

```
-(void) addCenterButtonWithImage:(UIImage*)buttonImage highlightImage:(UIImage*)highlightImage
```

Simply add the observer:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And then obviously implement:

```
-(void)click:(id)sender{
[self presentModalViewController:[[UIViewController alloc] init] animated:YES];
}
```

When my view controller appears, my tabbar disappears, how do I keep it on my screen?

Answer (score 0):

In your init-method, (or viewDidload - i don't see your github link) try this:

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
```